# Setting permanent environmental variables on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, environment-variables, bash

I want to set `NTA_CONF_PATH = /Users/macbook/nupic-master/nupic/support` as an environmental variable, but using

```
export NTA_CONF_PATH=/Users/macbook/nupic-master/nupic/support
```

is only  temporary, and every time I quit the Terminal, the environmental variable disappears and I have to type it again.
How do I make it permanent?

(I am running Yosemite.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Under the assumption that you use `bash` (the default shell in Mac OS X Yosemite), simply add the line

```
export NTA_CONF_PATH=/Users/macbook/nupic-master/nupic/support
```

to your `~/.bash_profile` file. Because this file is automatically sourced when you start `bash`, you won't have to type that line at the beginning of each session.